# Remove an object in an array of arrays in JavaScript or Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

I am trying to delete/remove an object which is at at position x in array A such that Array A is inside another array such as this:

```
    var lol = [ 
            [
              {'a':1},
              {'b':2},
              {'c':3}
            ], 
            [
              {'d':4},
              {'e':5},
              {'f':6}
            ], 
            [
              {'g':7},
              {'h':8},
              {'i':9}
            ]
];
```

Now lets say I would like to remove object with key `'f'`. I have a

```
function deleteNestedElement(outerIndex, innerIndex) {
        lol[outerIndex].splice(0, innerIndex);
}
```

on calling

```
deleteNestedElement(2,0);
alert(lol);
```

I am getting the result as this:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Here is my [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ahsan9981/z9mv3je4/13/)

I need to delete the specific element as desired from this array.

Comment: you get the same type of output if you alert(lol) before your function call.  you're alerting objects, not strings, so that's what your output is going to be.  Try doing a console.log instead, or using the browser debugging tools.

Comment: You need to read up on how `splice()` works. Also using `alert()` is a useless debugging tool for arrays of objects

Comment: @charlietfl, thanks, I was wondering if splice is doing something to array that is why it is like this in alert. I get it now.

Comment: How would you know when you can't see what's in each object? Logging to console lets you see changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove items [`Array.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) expects an index (1st param), and the number of items you wish to remove (2nd param). You passed 0 and 0 - remove 0 items from index 0, so nothing was removed.

In addition `alert()` converts JS objects to strings, and this is what you see. Use `console.log()` instead.

```js
function deleteNestedElement(outerIndex, innerIndex) {
  lol[outerIndex].splice(innerIndex, 1);
}

var lol = [[{"a":1},{"b":2},{"c":3}],[{"d":4},{"e":5},{"f":6}],[{"g":7},{"h":8},{"i":9}]];

deleteNestedElement(1, 2); // this will remove the "f" object
deleteNestedElement(2, 0); // this will remove the "g" object
console.log(lol);
```

Answer (score 2):

[Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) function takes first parameter as `index` and second parameter as number of elements to be deleted. In our case it should be `splice(innerIndex, 1)` as we need to delete 1 element at a particular index i.e. innerIndex.

Also, index of array start from 0, hence for 2nd item in array, you will need to pass 1 for outerIndex and similarly 2 for innerIndex like `deleteNestedElement(1,2)`

```js
var lol = [[{"a":1},{"b":2},{"c":3}],[{"d":4},{"e":5},{"f":6}],[{"g":7},{"h":8},{"i":9}]];

function deleteNestedElement(outerIndex, innerIndex) {
        lol[outerIndex].splice(innerIndex, 1);
}

deleteNestedElement(1,2);
console.log(lol);
```